# NLP-POS challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Please find the original question here on [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nlp-pos-tagging)

Although,my solution is incomplete can someone please help me understand  where I'm going wrong? (In the second function the tagger returns a 2-letter tag although the question asks for a 3-letter tag. Thanks!

```
import re
import nltk
import string
final_tagged = ""
raw_input(strs)
def tokenize_two(i):
    temp = i
    global strs
    "remove /?? and pos tag"
    for ch in ['/??']:
        if ch in i:
            i=i.replace(ch,"")
            #pos tagging
    tag = nltk.pos_tag([i])
    for item in tag:
        for ch in ['??']:
            if ch in temp:
                temp = temp.replace(ch,item[1])
    replace = i+"/??"
    strs = string.replace(strs,replace,temp)
    return temp;

def tokenize_three(i):
    "remove /??? and pos tag"
    temp = i 
    global strs
    for ch in ['/???']:
        if ch in i:
            i=i.replace(ch,"")
    tag = nltk.pos_tag([i])
    for item in tag:
        for ch in ['???']:
            if ch in temp:
                temp = temp.replace(ch,item[1])
    replace = i+"/???"
    strs = string.replace(strs,replace,temp)
    return temp;

a = [w for w in re.split('\s+',strs)]
for i in a :
    if(i.endswith("/??")):
        tagged = tokenize_two(i)
    if(i.endswith("/???")):
        final_tagged = tokenize_three(i)
print strs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tag = nltk.pos_tag([i])
```

POS tagging is context-dependent. You need to pass the entire tokenized sentence as an argument to `pos_tag`, rather than calling `pos_tag` one time for each unknown word.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are referring is asking you about Penn's POS tag not the POS tag embedded in NLTK library. Therefore, it will not the required answer as per your expectation.